# How to automatically show AdSense Vignette Ads when users arrive for the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, adsense

AdSense vignette ads is one of the automatic ads type from AdSense that will be showed by a trigger, which is  tag. So when the user click a link with  tag from the site, than the vignette ads will be showed.

[AdSense Vignette Ads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBZSs.jpg)

So what I want to do is to show this vignette ads automatically when users arrive, instead of when users click  tag. It's like on this site for example: https://lives.shoot-yalla.tv/

So far what I've done is putting this script on my footer:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var t;
if (jQuery) {
    console.log('Init page Loaded');
    console. log('jQuery version : ' + jQuery(). jquery);
t=setInterval(init,2500);
} else {
    console.log('Init page Not Loaded');
}
function init(){
    if ($("ins")[0]){
        console.log('init complete');
        jQuery('.adsbygoogle, .adsbygoogle-noablate').css("display", "inline");
     clearInterval(t);
//setInterval(init2,5000);
    } else {
        console.log('init not complete');
    }
}
function init2(){
jQuery('.adsbygoogle, .adsbygoogle-noablate').remove();
}
var ifr = document.getElementById("google_esf");
var isMouseIn;
ifr.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    isMouseIn = true;
});
ifr.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isMouseIn = false;
});
window.document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
    if (isMouseIn && document.hidden) {
        console.log("Click Recorded By Visibility Change");
    }
});
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
    if (isMouseIn) {
        console.log("Click Recorded By Before Unload");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

The result is so far: [https://dev.pendidikanpedia.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)
Vignette ads do appear when the users arrive, but the close button is not working.

Could anyone help me to make the vignette ads showed when users arrive and can be closed by a "X" button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying AdSense scripts is prohibited.
You can get an account ban.
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en